# Unable to login with Flask Login when deployed to Heroku using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a simple authentication page that uses Flask and Flask SQLAlchemy deployed on Heroku with PostgreSQL.

I was able to register users but was unable to log in.

Code for Log in:
`

```py
@indexbp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("You have already logged in!", 'success')
        return redirect('/')
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.hashed_password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                flash('You are logged in!', 'success')
                return redirect('/')
        except AttributeError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Wrong username, password or email. Please try again!', 'info')
            return redirect('/login')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Something went wrong inside our systems, please try again later. If this problem persists, please contact our admin team.', 'danger')
            return redirect('/login')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

`

Code for Register:
`

```py
@indexbp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("You have already logged in!", 'success')
        return redirect('/')
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            new_user = User(username=form.username.data, hashed_password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data), user_id=str(uuid.uuid1()))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/login')
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Something went wrong inside our systems, please try again later. If this problem persists, please contact our admin team.', 'danger')
            return redirect('/register')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

`

User table:
`

```py
#User table
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

`

Flask Configs:
`

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "link-to-database-provided-by-heroku"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "g3AbKqKhxhCACvFNlNgLv802LUBwXQKr4X4Z9J9d"
```

`

I have tried to migrate the database, rechecking it multiple times.
I have also attempted to run it locally but only registering works.

I installed psycopg2 as well as reconfiguring the User table.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @cavalcantelucas Not a single error, I tried catching the error and print it on the console but there were nothing.

Comment: You can visit the deployed site at https://phil-keegan-ielts.com/login for login and https://phil-keegan-ielts.com/register for registering. Users admin, and testuser has been registered, the password is the same as their username.

Comment: @BùiBảoHoàng, just to be sure, you registered those users on Heroku? Any data you might have created locally will not be present on the remote database.

Comment: @Chris Yes I registered those on Heroku, I just replicated what I did on a local machine to test.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Flask-Bcrypt not working properly. Changed my hashing function to md5 and it worked.